# Set QML node's property other than setProperty

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick3d

Is it possible to update the property "position" other than QQuick3DObject::setProperty ?

myQQuick3DObject->setProperty("position", QVector3D{x, y, z});

I am in a context where I receive from udp socket a large flow of updates per seconds for this property, and I can not help thinking that looking for a property in a list is a real bottleneck.

Intuitively, I tell myself that I'm not doing it the right way. QQuick3DNode class could have met my need but is private.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick-performance.html First paragraph.

Comment: If you are receiving a large flow of updates, is it possible to skip some of them? Also, alternative to setProperty() the documentation says you can also use `QQmlProperty(mQQuick3DObject, "position").write(value);` I dunno if you will get a performance improvement with the latter.